# Como cambiar el metodo de entrada de un Edit text en java?

Tags: android, entrada

Hola estoy programando en android studio y necesito saber como cambiar el metodo de entrada (inputType) de un Edit text con codigo java, no desde xml.

```
public void button (View view){
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    table.addView(tableRow);

    EditText fecha = new EditText(this);
    EditText monto = new EditText(this);

    fecha.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8)});
    monto.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(5)});

    //aca quiero indicar el metodo InputType del editText pero no me sale al 
    //hacer fecha.

    tableRow.addView(fecha);
    tableRow.addView(monto);
```

Comment: Te refieres al Input Type? Explica mejor que quieres hacer y pon un ejemplo por favor de lo que has intentado hasta ahora

Comment: Bienvenido Lucho, tienes realizado algo de esto? , revisa [ask] , te invito también a realizar el [tour] para que obtengas tu primera medalla!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `.setInputType()` te permite asignar el tipo del método de entrada en un EditText.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo para asignarle el modo de entrada de una password a un `EditText` llamado editPass:

```
editPass.setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Aquí te dejo un enlace a la [documentacion de Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) donde tienes todos los tipos de método de entrada que puedes asignar.

Comment: Era lo que necesitaba muchas gracias!

Comment: Si es lo que buscabas marcala como respuesta valida.